# X-editable prevent the default behavior of input box close on focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

How can I prevent the default behavior of closing the x-editable input box when the focus changed to something else?.

My requirement is to keep the input box open until a click on the tick or cross button happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `{onblur: "ignore"}`.

From the [documentation](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html):

> Action when the user clicks outside the container. Can be `cancel|submit|ignore`.
>   Setting `ignore` allows having several containers open.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/jjdJX/791/), or the below demo.

```js
$(function() {

  $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
  $('#publicname-change').editable({ onblur:"ignore"})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="control-group control-group-inline">
  <div class="controls">
    <a href="#" id="publicname-change" class="editable editable-click inline-input">Mr.Rohith</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is very important to always indicate that you quote some other page. Also, always try to make your answers self-contained, so that they are still valid when a site you link to goes offline (JSFiddle in this case). I have edited your answer to do so, hope you don't mind and can apply this in the future :-)

Comment: @Ninja This solved my problem simply like 123 :)! Really appreciate your support! Thank you!